# HTML Frame Source

Tags: html, frame, frameset

Hey is it possible that I insert the source for a frame in the same page in which it is defined.

Like instead of giving the location to the document, can I insert the source in the frame tag?

The problem is I'm calling a function, which is not valid in the other page. So I have to call it in the same page, Got me?

Comment: perhaps you might consider rewriting your frame as a div. cross-page JS is always a headache.

Comment: well i'll, if no other options were available (i dont think there are any)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are able to do this with the `data:` tag.

`<iframe src="data:<source of the page>">`. That is how Yahoo recommends for images, so I expect it might work the same from source code.

Another Idea is you can create an empty frame with no source and then use Javascript/jQuery to add HTML.

Comment: yes though i'd check browser support. ie is pretty slow on the uptake of features like this and i'm reasonably sure ie6 doesn't support data: